# Do we considered Yoav a Tzadik (righteous)?

Tags: tanach, navi-prophets, melachim-kings-book-of

It often seems that Yoav is referred to as righteous, however, navi scripture also lambasts him for the various killings, disregarding orders, and disloyalty to David, culminating in Solomon having him killed. How do we reconcile the dichotomy?

Comment: How does it seem he was righteous? You only have examples of how he wasn't

Comment: @robev there are several that come to mind. 
Sanhedrin 49a:16
With regard to Joab: “And he was buried in his own house, in the wilderness” (I Kings 2:34). Is that to say that Joab’s house was a wilderness? Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: Joab’s house was like the wilderness; just as the wilderness is freely open to all, so too, Joab’s house was freely open to all, as he generously opened his house to the poor and made them feel like members of the household.

Comment: 2.
Alternatively, Joab’s house was like the wilderness; just as the wilderness is clean of theft and sexual immorality, as it is uninhabited, so too, Joab’s house was clean of theft and sexual immorality, owing to his righteousness. As for the verse: “And Joab kept alive the rest of the city” (I Chronicles 11:8), Rav Yehuda says: Not only would Joab feed the poor, but he would even give them treats of types of small fish so they would lack for nothing

Comment: There are many examples of people who did amazing things as well as wicked things. Achav honored Torah scholars yet he was an idol worshipper. Why focus in Yoav?

Comment: @robev there are lots of sources to prove he was a tzaddik in various midrashim, I can post some sources later it you would like

Comment: He was a righteous person who erred in some matters.

Comment: @Dov please do! thanks!

Comment: @yishairasowsky - posted an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned, for the most part Yoav is regarded as a Tzaddik who unfortunately erred which led to his eventual demise.

The Gemara in [Sanhedrin 49a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.49a.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) has already been mentioned in the comments that Yoav's house was open to all, or alternatively is to be understood as being clean from theft or immorality, but it also adds there the verse from [Divrei HaYamim I 11:8](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.11.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> וְיוֹאָ֕ב יְחַיֶּ֖ה אֶת־שְׁאָ֥ר הָעִֽיר
>
> And Yoav kept alive the rest of the city

The gemara understands from there that he made a point of not only sustaining the poor but even going so far as providing them with various kinds of delicacies.

In addition, it is worth noting the [Pesikta Rabbasi 11](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_Rabbati.11.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) which sheds more light on how much of a tzaddik Yoav was. Firstly it notes:

> אמר לו יוסף ה' על העם כהם וכהם מאה פעמים (שמואל שם ג') ולמה לא אמר כברכת משה רבו משה אמר יוסף עליכם ככם אלף פעמים (דברים א' י"א) ויואב אמר מאה פעמים אלא ברכתו של יואב הייתה טובה משל משה אמר ועיני אדני המלך רואות (שמואל שם שם) אמר לו בימיך יהא כן
>
> He (Yoav) said to him (Dovid), "May the LORD your G-d increase the number of the people a hundredfold" ([Shmuel II 24:3](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.24.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). And why did he not say it like the blessing of Moshe? Moshe said "Increase your numbers a thousandfold" ([Devarim 1:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.1.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - i.e. Yoav said "hundredfold"? Rather it must be be that Yoav's blessing was better than that of Moshe. He (Yoav) said, "While your own eyes see it" (Shmuel Ibid.) i.e. Yoav said to Dovid that the blessing will be in your lifetime.

And then it continues:

> ואתה מוצא חכם יושב ראשו של סנהדרין היה יושב בשבת תחכמוני (שם כ"ג ח') הוא היה יואב שהיה גדול בתורה וגיבור במלחמה
>
> And you find that he (Yoav) was a sage that sat as the head of the Sanhedrin. He was Yosheiv Basheves Tachkemoni ([Shmuel 23:8](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.23.8?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)) - this was Yoav who was great in Torah and mighty in battle.

So from Pesikta Rabbasi we find in addition to the Gemara in Sanhedrin that shows his charitable side, that his blessing to Dovid was further reaching than Moshe's equivalent bracha as it would be realised in Dovid's lifetime, and that he was also considered a great sage.